# How to insert row and change cell styles using batch_update in gspread?

Tags: python, google-sheets, gspread

I am using `gspread` and `gspread_formatting` to update my sheets in Google. Some of my codebase has been reworked to use `batch_update`, because I found some code samples in another answer that I could use as reference. However, I can't seem to convert two other operations. Here is my code:

```
import gspread

from gspread_formatting import *
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

def operate():
    scope = [
        'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
    ]
    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
        'creds.json',
        scope
    )
    gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)

    sh = gc.open('My spreadsheet')
    ws = sh.sheet1
    sheet_id = ws._properties['sheetId']

    # Setting the column sizes
    body = {
        'requests': [
            {
                'updateDimensionProperties': {
                    'range': {
                        'sheetId': sheet_id,
                        'dimension': 'COLUMNS',
                        'startIndex': 0,
                        'endIndex': 10
                    },
                    'properties': {
                        'pixelSize': 150
                    },
                    'fields': 'pixelSize'
                }
            },
            {
                'updateDimensionProperties': {
                    'range': {
                        'sheetId': sheet_id,
                        'dimension': 'COLUMNS',
                        'startIndex': 4,
                        'endIndex': 6
                    },
                    'properties': {
                        'pixelSize': 250
                    },
                    'fields': 'pixelSize'
                }
            }
        ]
    }
    res = sh.batch_update(body)

    # Request 1
    ws.insert_row(['One', 'Two', 'Three'], 1)

    # Request 2
    format_cell_range(
        ws, 'A1:Z7',
        cellFormat(
            wrapStrategy='WRAP',
            verticalAlignment='MIDDLE',
            backgroundColor=color(0.886, 0.945, 0.988),
            textFormat=textFormat(
                foregroundColor=color(0, 0.129, 0.443),
                fontFamily='Roboto',
                bold=True
            )
        )
    )
```

So, what I want to do is somehow add request 1 and request 2 into the `bulk_update` method. Is it possible to insert and a row and change formatting using `bulk_update`? If yes, how can I do this? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You want to insert new row to the 1st row.
- You want to put the values of `['One', 'Two', 'Three']` to the inserted row.
- You want to set the following cell format to the range of "A1:Z7" using the method of `batch_update()` of gspread.

  ```
  wrapStrategy='WRAP',
  verticalAlignment='MIDDLE',
  backgroundColor=gsf.color(0.886, 0.945, 0.988),
  textFormat=gsf.textFormat(
      foregroundColor=gsf.color(0, 0.129, 0.443),
      fontFamily='Roboto',
      bold=True
  )
  ```
- You want to achieve this using gspread with python.

  - Your goal is to convert the following script to `batch_update()`

    ```
    # Request 1
    ws.insert_row(['One', 'Two', 'Three'], 1)

    # Request 2
    format_cell_range(
        ws, 'A1:Z7',
        cellFormat(
            wrapStrategy='WRAP',
            verticalAlignment='MIDDLE',
            backgroundColor=color(0.886, 0.945, 0.988),
            textFormat=textFormat(
                foregroundColor=color(0, 0.129, 0.443),
                fontFamily='Roboto',
                bold=True
            )
        )
    )
    ```
- You have already been able to get and put values for Spreadsheet using Sheets API.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Flow:

In this case, the flow of the request body of `batch_update()` is as follows.

1. Insert new row to the 1st row by `insertDimension`.
2. Put the values of `['One', 'Two', 'Three']` to the inserted row by `updateCells`.
3. Set the cell format to the range of "A1:Z7" by `repeatCell`.

#### Modified script:

```
spreadsheetId = "###"  # Please set the Spreadsheet ID.
sheetName = "###"  # Please set the sheet name.

sh = gc.open_by_key(spreadsheetId)
ws = sh.worksheet(sheetName)
sheetId = ws._properties['sheetId']
requests = {
    "requests": [
        {
            "insertDimension": {
                "range": {
                    "sheetId": sheetId,
                    "startIndex": 0,
                    "dimension": "ROWS",
                    "endIndex": 1
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "updateCells": {
                "range": {
                    "sheetId": sheetId,
                    "startRowIndex": 0,
                    "endRowIndex": 1
                },
                "rows": [
                    {
                        "values": [
                            {
                                "userEnteredValue": {
                                    "stringValue": "One"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "userEnteredValue": {
                                    "stringValue": "Two"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "userEnteredValue": {
                                    "stringValue": "Three"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "fields": "userEnteredValue"
            }
        },
        {
            "repeatCell": {
                "range": {
                    "sheetId": sheetId,
                    "startRowIndex": 0,
                    "endRowIndex": 7,
                    "startColumnIndex": 0,
                    "endColumnIndex": 26
                },
                "cell": {
                    "userEnteredFormat": {
                        "wrapStrategy": "WRAP",
                        "verticalAlignment": "MIDDLE",
                        "backgroundColor": {
                            "red": 0.886,
                            "green": 0.945,
                            "blue": 0.988
                        },
                        "textFormat": {
                            "foregroundColor": {
                                "red": 0,
                                "green": 0.129,
                                "blue": 0.443
                            },
                            "fontFamily": "Roboto",
                            "bold": True
                        }
                    }
                },
                "fields": "userEnteredFormat"
            }
        }
    ]
}
res = sh.batch_update(requests)
```

#### Note:

- I understood that `bulk_update` is `batch_update`.

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [insertDimension](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#insertdimensionrequest)
- [updateCells](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatecellsrequest)
- [repeatCell](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#repeatcellrequest)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: Wow that is like the perfect answer. Thank you so much!

Comment: @darkhorse Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.